# Including properties of a one to many or many to many in LINQ .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Having created a many to many relation using code first using similar classes to:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Categorization> Categorizations { get; set; }
}

class Categorization
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Categorization> Categorizations { get; set; }
}
```

And the following for a composite key in the dbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Categorization>().HasKey(x => new { x.ProductId , x.CategoryId });
}
```

I have tried to return JSON of a Product containing all its Categories, or vice-versa.
Using this method:

```
var prod = _context.Products
            .Include(p => p.Categorization)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1));
```

I get

```
{
"product": {
  "id": 1,
  "categorizations": [
    {
      "categoryId": 1
    }
  ]
}
}
```

This also cuts off anything which would have come after, e.g Another field.

Using this method:

```
var prod= _context.Products
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    p.Id,
                    p.Categorization
                })
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
```

I get

```
{
"product": {
  "id": 1,
  "categorizations": [
    {
    "categoryId": 1,
    "category": null,
    "productId": 1,
    "product": null
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "category": null,
    "productId": 1,
    "product": null
  },
  ]
}
}
```

How can I:

1. Get the properties of the referenced object "category" using include.
2. Get the properties of the referenced object "category" using select.
3. Also, slightly off topic, can I query on a field which is not being "selected". Example being I wanted to search for a product by Id, but return only the other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you reading the [Loading Related Data](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html) section from the documentation.

Here are the answers to (some of) your concrete questions:

> (1) Get the properties of the referenced object "category" using include.

You should use `ThenInclude`:

```
var prod = _context.Products
            .Include(p => p.Categorization)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.Category)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1));
```

> (2) Get the properties of the referenced object "category" using select.

You can use nested *projection* (select):

```
var prod = db.Products
            .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                p.Id,
                Categories = p.Categorizations.Select(c => c.Category).ToList()
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

What about question (3), you need to provide a concrete example in order to get a concrete answer.

Comment: Apologies, question 3 was an error on my part. After reading the docs and using your examples I was able to get quite a few things the way I wanted. I am now struggling with including grandchildren within the list. So if for example categories had a 1:1 relationship with say "CategoryType", how would one manage to get that in the list using Select? I am new here so I'm not sure how if I should append this question onto the end of the original?

Comment: Well, you could use the navigation property and another sub select, e.g. `c => new { c.Category.Id, c.Category.Name, ..., c.Category.CategoryType }` etc. Similar to how you write SQL queries, but w/o a need to specify joins - you just "navigate" and EF does joins for you.

Comment: There is no way to "load" using select. You either select the fields / sub fields you want (in which case they are not really "entities"), OR use Include/ThenInclude chains.

Comment: Regarding *I am new here so I'm not sure how if I should append this question onto the end of the original?* No, you shouldn't. In general it is expected every post to contain one question. You can post another question, and optionally link it to this one as follow up if you wish.

Comment: Using this method it gives me a separate element of the queried object named "categories" containing the categories. Leaving me with a "categories" : null, within the element I hoped it would be in. I feel now I should have included my actual code instead of typical example material. Essentially I have object A, with a M:1 to object B, object B has a M:M with object C. Object A also has a 1:1 with object D, which has a M:1 to object E. There is also a M:1 with object F. I am trying to get all these results while avoiding any circular references in the M:M, while excluding object F.

Comment: Would an alternative be to use includes to get everything, then just format appropriately afterwards? The problem I encountered using includes was circular reference issues as the joining table contains X.Id, X, Y.Id, Y. I wish only to include the Y's.

Comment: Unfortunately the comment space is not enough to cover the scenario. I would suggest you posting another question, explaining exactly what you did in the previous 2 comments, providing a simple model (shouldn't be a big deal) and the exact goal, so the people can play with it and see if someone can find a solution.

Comment: Alright thanks for the guidance. I have created a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836751/linq-ef7-include-select-specific-properties-and-specific-properties-of-related. I hope it's clear enough.